# z3 @ command line behaving differently than online

Tags: z3, smt

the (rather small) query that I have here:

http://rise4fun.com/Z3/W4sf

works just fine on the website (above) but hangs 
when I run it on my mac, with

```
z3 -in
```

followed by pasting in the exact text above, which is:

```
(declare-const x Real)
(assert (not (= 0.0 x)))
(assert (not (< 0.0 (* x x))))
(check-sat)
```

Any ideas? I thought it might be that I have an old version but its 4.3.2

```
rjhala@borscht ~/bin [130]> z3 -help
Z3 [version 4.3.2 - 64 bit - build hashcode 5b5a474b5443].
```

Am I missing some parameters? Or any other suggestions? Many thanks!

Ranjit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also seemed not to return for me using that, but it seems to work as:

```
z3 -in -smt2
```

Followed by pasting the query, so I think it may need the -smt2 parameter. I tried it on Windows with 4.3.3 (I thought I had 4.3.2, but it seems I updated from the latest unstable branch):

```
C:\Users\tjohnson>z3 -in -smt2
(declare-const x Real)
(assert (not (= 0.0 x)))
(assert (not (< 0.0 (* x x))))
(check-sat)
unsat
```

It also worked for me by pasting the query into test.smt and running:

```
C:\Users\tjohnson>z3 -smt2 test.smt
unsat
```

Comment: That's right, -smt2 is not the default format for -in, so we need to add -smt2. If I remember correctly, the default is still the old SMT1 format.